# Wordpress passing query parameters from page to page

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I would like to pass query string parameters from one page to another in wordpress. The problem im facing is wordpress always removes the ?get queries everytime a new page loads - hence there's no way i can pass the parameters.

Ideal flow ==>

Affiliate sends traffic to my domain using link:

http://domain.com/pricing/?id=123&no=456

User lands on this website and starts reading. User then decides to navigate to e.g. the "about-us" section by clicking somewhere on the page's menu.

User then gets redirected to domain.com/about-us

[(query string parameters) got stripped!]

What can I do to make sure the query parameters stay?

What can i do to get the user redirected to domain.com/about-us/?id=123&no=456 ?

In general, I wish that the whole query string "?id=123&no=456" can be passed from one page to another, until user closes the window.

I'm trying to be as clear as I can but I apologise if I'm not explaning too well on this!

Appreciate if anyone can lend a helping hand! all forms (keep it simple please) of answers will be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to send Post parameters instead of GET? Or maybe you want to store those parameters into session if you want parameters to `be passed from one page to another, until user closes the window`

Comment: Or you can store them inside a `cookie` :)

Comment: The website is designed in such way where the information in the URL is pulled out and presented on the screen. I need the query string to be passed so the other pages can use it :)

Comment: i have though about storing them into a cookie, but that would also mean the function used to pull values out from the URL wouldnt work anymore. Hence giving myself more trouble / work. same thing for storing values as session variable also!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your functions.php:

```
function append_query_string($url) {
    return add_query_arg($_GET, $url);
}
add_filter('the_permalink', 'append_query_string');
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_permalink

Comment: hi! thanks for that! but i tried to add the lines into function.php (i added it at the end of all the other codes) but it didnt help.Query string still didnt get passed! Am i missing out in something?

Comment: The above code will append the current page's query string parameters to all permalinks that are built by wordpress. How are your links (i.e. your about-us link) being built in the code?