# Add GET request value to the end of a URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, get

I have a WooCommerce form on the category pages which allows the user to select the number of products to be shown on the page. The values are 24, 48 and all. When one of the options is selected, the form is submitted. The issue I have is the GET value is replacing the existing values in my URL whereas I need the value adding to the end of the URL.

For example, if my URL is: [www.example.com/?s=cars&post_type=product&type_aws=true](http://www.example.com/?s=cars&post_type=product&type_aws=true) and I update the form, the URL becomes: [www.example.com/?show=48](http://www.example.com/?show=48) whereas I need it to be added to the end like so:
[www.example.com/?s=cars&post_type=product&type_aws=true&show=48](http://www.example.com/?s=cars&post_type=product&type_aws=true&show=48)

Here is my HTML Form:

```
<form class="woocommerce-results-per-page" method="get">
  <span>Show</span>
    <select class="autosubmit" name="show">
      <option value="48">48</option>
      <option value="24">24</option>
      <option value="-1">All</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="orderby" value="rating">
</form>
```

Here is my jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $(document).ready(function()
        {
             $( '.autosubmit' ).each( function()
           {
                $( this ).on( 'change' , null , function()
             {
                $( this ).parents( 'form' ).submit();
            });
        } );
    });

});
```

Comment: Where are you creating the url with all GET parameters ? I think some JS code is missing from your exemple. The easiest way will be adding hidden fields to you form to keep them between pages (not the cleanest way)

Comment: The URL with all GET parameters is from a search on the site. So if I search for 'books' it takes me to a WooCommerce shop page with those values in the URL.

Comment: Ok that's what I thought. You are not supposed to keep all your GET parameters from a page to an other etc. You should search for alternative like caching or session variables.  This can help you ,  maybe there is an equivalent for wooCommerce https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40897349/wordpress-passing-query-parameters-from-page-to-page

Comment: Use session_start(); then pass variable to your session $_SESSION['myKey']; - here is a helpful article - https://silvermapleweb.com/using-the-php-session-in-wordpress/

Comment: Be aware of Session variables vulnerabilities https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/126825/php-session-vulnerability

Comment: @sc2015 Just saw your question. Still looking for an answer? If so, then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        let select = $('.autosubmit');
        url = new URL(window.location.href);
        show = url.searchParams.get("show");
        if (show !== null) {
            select.find(`option[value="${show}"]`).prop('selected',true)
        }


        select.each(function () {
            $(this).on('change', null, function () {
                let url = window.location.search;
                let params = url.substring(1, url.length).split('&');
                let hidden_inputs = '';
                let form = $(this).parents('form');

                $.each(params, function (i, el) {
                    let param = el.split('=');
                    if (form.find(`select[name="${param[0]}"],input[name="${param[0]}"]`).length == 0) {
                        hidden_inputs += `<input type="hidden" name="${param[0]}" value="${param[1]}">`;
                    }
                });
                
                form.prepend(hidden_inputs).submit();
                
            });
        });
    });
```